# transform character to number

Tags: r

This:

```
df <- data.frame(
    x = "50,000.00"
)

as.numeric(df$x)
```

Does not result in the number 50000. What could I do to obtain the number 50000 please?

Comment: `as.numeric(sub(",", "", df$x))` as `,` is not considered in the numeric

Comment: down-vote - why?!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Remove the `,` part as it is a `character` and then it should work

```
as.numeric(sub(",", "", df$x))
#[1] 50000
```

If there are multiple instances of `,`, use `gsub` (global substitution) instead of `sub`

---

Another option is `parse_number` which will work on `character` class.  Here, the `data.frame` is created with default settings (`stringsAsFactors = TRUE`)

```
readr::parse_number(as.character(df$x))
#[1] 50000
```